# Can't edit file in emacs without sudo

Tags: lubuntu, emacs

I have lubuntu 12.04, and I installed emacs using:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

Whenever I try to edit/make a file, however, nothing shows up unless I run it under sudo. So I need to type in

```
sudo emacs "filename"
```

everytime. Can anyone help me out? This is really annoying.

Comment: Is it system file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a permission issue on the current directory you were working on.
And the file you created is not your ownership since you send a sudo command on it.

Try to check your current directory's permission.

If you don't have permission to it you can have

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 Your_Directory/
```

or

change the ownership of that directory.

```
$ sudo chown -R user Your_Directory/
```

Next time you create a file just type

```
$ emacs "Your File in Here"
```

Comment: Well the directory I was working in had the correct permissions. What I had to do was

    sudo chmod -R 755 /home/username/.emacs.d/

I don't know what is up with that directory, but when I did that, it worked.

Comment: @de1337ed You may have created it as root or had root privileges at the time.

Answer (score 4):

chown and chgrp -R  on the .emacs.d directory. It looks like it is owned by root by default for some reason,.